# Why does Xcode 8.1 + Metal. crash the Timer I use to manipulate my 3D model?

Tags: nstimer, metal

I have an arcball manipulator that uses a `Timer` to create a smoothly decelerating attenuation of the current rotation angle. It has been working just fine in my `GL` app. In `Metal`, it crashes the app.

Here is how I instantiate the timer:

```
rotationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
timeInterval: TimeInterval(kRotationRate), 
target: self,
selector: Selector(("rotationTimerHandler")),
userInfo: [ "radiansBegin":radians, "radians":radians, "radiansEnd":0, "counter":0 ],
repeats: true)
```

The function `rotationTimerHandler` decrements the angle - `radians` - and then builds a transformation matrix from it that gets include in the update function of my render draw loop.

I suspect I need to do some synchronization with timing of the `Metal` draw loop but I see no way to do that. How do I get `Timer` and `Metal` to play nice together?

### UPDATE 0

Per Warren's question storm :-) here is a bit more context.

My app's view is an `MTKView` with 2 properties.

A renderer that conforms to `MTKViewDelegate` protocol and implements:

```
func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize)
func draw(in view: MTKView)
```

Drawing is driven by the MTKView's internal display link timer. Everything runs on the main thread. No async calls.

and an arcball. An object that maps screen gestures to a quaternion to a 3D rotation matrix. The arcball is a pan gesture handler for the view:

```
addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(
    target: arcBall,
    action: #selector(EIArcball.arcBallPanHandler)))
```

}

When the arcball's pan gesture handler enter's an end state I instantiate a timer for N seconds to continue generationg quaternions/matrices based on the angle/axis of rotation when panning ended for a pleasing, gliding effect.

Ok, the renderer (which conforms to `MTKViewDelegate`). The draw loop:

```
public func draw(in view: MTKView) {

    update(view: view as! EIView, drawableSize: view.bounds.size)

    // final pass
    if let passDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor, let drawable = view.currentDrawable {

        passDescriptor.colorAttachments[ 0 ].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)

        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()

        let renderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: passDescriptor)

        renderCommandEncoder.setFrontFacing(.counterClockwise)
        renderCommandEncoder.setTriangleFillMode(.fill)
        renderCommandEncoder.setCullMode(.none)

        renderCommandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(heroModelPipelineState)
        renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(heroModel.vertexMetalBuffer, offset: 0, at: 0)
        renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(heroModel.metallicTransform.metalBuffer, offset: 0, at: 1)
        renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(heroModelTexture, at: 0)
        renderCommandEncoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(
                type: .triangle,
                indexCount: heroModel.vertexIndexMetalBuffer.length / MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size,
                indexType: MTLIndexType.uint16,
                indexBuffer: heroModel.vertexIndexMetalBuffer,
                indexBufferOffset: 0)

        renderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }

}
```

Nothing particularly interesting here. Notice the call:

```
update(view: view as! EIView, drawableSize: view.bounds.size)
```

Here is `update`

```
func update(view: EIView, drawableSize:CGSize) {

    heroModel.metallicTransform.update(camera: camera, transformer: {
        return view.arcBall.rotationMatrix * GLKMatrix4MakeScale(150, 150, 1)
    })

}
```

function `heroModel.metallicTransform.update(...)` builds a model-view-projection matrix used in my vertex shader. This is a toy app that draws a quad scaled in x-y by 150 that is manipulated (rotated) by pan gestures fed to the arcball.

In `update` I make no attempt to schedule the feeding of arcball's transformation matrix to update. That seems like a code smell.

Here is the crasher screendump:
[image]

The more I think about this it seems I should just make my draw calls explicitly since I have no real need to be constantly redraw-ing.
1) When panning just call renderer.draw().
2) After panning ends call render.draw() from my Timer handler.

### UPDATE 1

Here is more stack trace. Just a whole lot of assembler:

[image]

### UPDATE 2

The output of bt (backtrace):

[image]

I think I will experiment running `Metal` **without** the internal timer and call `MTKView.draw()` explicitly. No need for a timer-based approach in such a simple app and issues with my `NSTimer` based Arcball.

Comment: Are you using `MTKView`? If so, are you using its internal display link timer, or are you leaving it paused and running your own render loop timer? If not, how are you driving your render loop? Is the transformation matrix updated on the main thread, or are you doing that asynchronously? Do you do perform your drawing with Metal on the main thread, or asynchronously? Are you copying the transformation matrix into a buffer, or letting Metal manage the buffer for you with `setVertexBytes`? Where does the crash occur? Is it something like a bad access exception or a validation failure?

Comment: Thanks for the extra info! If you expand the call stack (first little blue button at the bottom of the Debug navigator), what's actually calling `abort`? Are there any messages on the console?

Comment: I added another update with stack trace info.

Comment: That stack trace is still collapsed. Click the first blue button at the bottom of the Debug navigator or run `bt` in the debugger. Something is calling `abort`, probably as the result of a failed assertion.

Comment: Update 2 shows the backtrace for an irrelevant background thread. Try `bt all` to get the backtrace for all threads and look at the stack for the main thread (#1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I decided to bail on using the `MTKView` internal timer and just call `MTKView.draw()` explicitly in `Arcball` during panning **and** in the NSTimer callback. Easy peasy. Works identically.

Code: https://github.com/turner/HelloMetal

Comment: I've had great success with bailing as well on the internal timer (or setNeedsDisplay) means of calling `MTKView.draw()` and instead  dispatching the draw call from an async queue from within a `CVDisplayLink`.  This way of doing things prevented render lag when mousing up on menu items within a desktop app.